# Taking panorama image using the Cordova plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, panoramas

Is possible to take panorama image using the some cordova plugin (in X and Y axiss) ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

The camera plugin starts the device's camera app, so I guess that on a phone with a camera app that does panorama you can take panorama from a cordova app (the user would have to select the function manually).

Otherwise you would have to either

- build a plugin in native code to start a different app that does panorama or
- build a plugin with it's own camera view and you would have to code yourself the panorama function or
- try to use the HTML5 api that allow access to the camera to do the panorama

Comment: 'Photo' is the only option I get from iOS. No 'Video', no 'Pano'. Should there be a particular option passed in camera options when opening the camera?